# Tweet clickable links on website?

Tags: html, twitter

Right, based on this question [Tweet clickable links with twitteroauth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984441/tweet-clickable-links-with-twitteroauth),

How do I actually parse the entire string and replace the t.co link portion with a

```
<a href=""></a>
```

portion?

For example i tweet this -

```
Hey check out this link www.google.com
```

and in my website currently it shows

```
Hey check out this link http://t.co/generatedlink
```

So how do i parse it and make it into this

```
Hey check out this link <a href="http://t.co/generatedlink">http://t.co/generatedlink</a>
```

which would display like this in my website:

Hey check out this link http://t.co/generatedlink

How am I able to detect that a certain portion of the tweet text has a link inside it? Or am I going about this wrong?

Comment: Have a answer for you, see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand [Twitter Entities](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities).

When you request the tweet, make sure you use include_entities=true

For example:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show.json?id=220197158798897155&include_entities=true
```

In the response, you will see an element called "entities" inside that, you will see "urls".

That will contain all the URLs and their position (indices) within the tweet.

```
"text": "Twitter for Mac is now easier and faster, and you can open multiple windows at once http://t.co/0JG5Mcq",

"entities": {

  "urls": [

    {

      "url": "http://t.co/0JG5Mcq",

      "display_url": "blog.twitter.com/2011/05/twitte…",

      "expanded_url": "http://blog.twitter.com/2011/05/twitter-for-mac-update.html",

      "indices": [

        84,

        103

      ]

    }

  ],

}
```

Comment: so if i were to do it, i would find the same url in "text" with "url", and then change it into a <a href> link?

Comment: Yes, you can just do a simple regex looking for "url" and add the a href

Answer (score 0):

```
function urlify(text) {
    var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
    return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
        return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
    })}

var text = "Hey check out this link http://t.co/generatedlink";
var a = urlify(text);
alert(a);
```

The above solution is perfect for your needs. I have a Fiddle link too Check it out http://jsfiddle.net/UhzCx/

I got this answer here [Detect URLs in text with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500260/detect-urls-in-text-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use javascript, here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/3VF96/13/

Function

```
function generateURL(text){
   var str=text;
    var n=str.indexOf("http");
    var strv=str.substring(0,n);
    var link=str.substring(n,str.length);
    strv=strv+" <a href='"+link+"'>"+link+"</a>";
      $("#Link").append(strv);
}
​
```